# How unique is the IIS sessionid on IIS 5, IIS6 and IIS7?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

Can the Sessionid from a given IIS server repeat after a reboot?  How likely is it that the same session id will be used a second time by two different clients on the same IIS server?  On a different IIS server?  Please see example:

```
SaveFile "DocumentName" & Session.SessionID & ".html"
```

Is there a difference between IIS 5.0, 6.0, and 7.0 regarding session id? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [higher than zero chance that SessionIDs will repeat](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2004/09/13/228713.aspx), additionally there is no guarantee the same user will pick up the same SessionID on a repeat visit.

More information is available in this [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q184574/).